# Suppose that u is a d x 1 vector such that ||u|| =1. What information does it implied to us?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

We know that the the norm of a vector is $\| \vec{u} \| = \sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2 + ... + u_n^2}$, where $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  How does the d x 1 vector look like using the definition of  norm, and what does $\mathbb{R}^n$ really means? Or what is $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the d x 1 vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is on the unit sphere.

It might help to work with lower specific number of $n$, say $n=1,2,3$.

If $n=1$, then $u=1$ or $u=-1$.

If $n=2$, then it lies on the unit circle, $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$.

If $n=3$, then it lies on the unit circle, $u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2=1$

$\mathbb{R}^2$ means $\{(x,y)^T|x, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, similary for general $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: so n is the dimensions,  and $\mathbb{R}$ means all possible real number?

Comment: $n$ controls the length of the vector. $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers.

Comment: ok, just wondering, with the given information, we can't determine the dimension of the vector ?

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to use the word "dimension" as I usually use the word to refer to the number of elements in a basis of a vector space. but I believe you are referring to the lnegth?, then the length is $n$.

Comment: yes. got you when you say that n controls the length of the vector, which means the number of vectors in a matrix. but do we have any information about the single vectors itself, as to refer to the number of elements in a basis of a vector space. or we just don't care about that information now.

Comment: Dimension of $\operatorname{Span}\{(0,1)\}$ is $1$ but dimension of $\operatorname{Span}\{(0,1), (1,2)\}$ is $2$, looking at a particular vector doesn't tell you about the subspace.